# Is there any way to improve spark write performance?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am working on moving data from elasticsearch to hdfs.
The data size is about 200GB, and 80 million datas.

here is my code. very simple. just read es and then write to hdfs.

```
// 1. config setting
public Map<String, String> esConfigParam() {
        return new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, String>()
                .put("es.nodes", params.getEsNodes())
                .put("es.mapping.date.rich", "false")
                .put("pushdown", "true")
                .put("es.scroll.size", params.getScrollSize())
                .put("es.read.field.as.array.include","label")
                .put("es.input.json", "true")
                .put("es.read.metadata", "true").build();
    }

// 2. load ES data
Dataset<Row> dataSet = JavaEsSparkSQL.esDF(session.getSqlContext(), indexAlias, esConfigParam());

// 3. write to hdfs
dataSet.write()
            .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
            .option("compression", "gzip")
            .parquet(params.getWritePath());
```

I am thinking of below as a tuning point to improve performance.

1. Spark Setting :
   executor-cores 5 / num-executors 16 / executor-memory 4g / driver-memory 4g
2. ES read Setting : params.getScrollSize()=2000

It takes about 30 minutes in this situation.
Please tell me how to shorten the time by improving the write performance.
(ex. apply colesce(10) ??)

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting question!

For the discussion porposes, I assume that your cluster have 4 nodes, 16 cores each node and 64GB each node.

(for your particular case you need to know this information and apply the example below)

You can't use all the resources of your cluster because of three reasons:

- Each node needs, at least, 1 core and 1GB to run OS and YARN processes.
- Maybe other applications may can use the cluster at same time.
- We assume that AM is running in one of the nodes.

Well, after that, really you have 4 nodes, 15 cores/node and 63GB/node free for use.

You can think a good idea must be to take --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 15 --executor-memory 63G, but not!

The reasons:

- First you have consider the memory overhead (aprox 7% of executor memeory), that is 63GB + 7% = 67.41 > 64GB
- Second you will use all cores in nodes, but you need 1 aditional core in one of them to run the AM (Application Manager)
- And finally, 15 cores per executor can lead to bad HDFS I/O throughput.

A good approach would be --num-executors 11 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 19G:

- Node 1,2,3: will use 3 executors and 12 cores each node (3 cores free for SO and other processes)
- Node 4: will use 2 executors and 8 cores (the other 8 cores free for AM, SO and other processes)
- Each executor will use 19GB + 7% (overhead) = 20.33GB
- Node 1,2,3: will use 20.33 * 3 executors = 60.99GB (3GB free)
- Node 4: will use 40,66GB (23,44 GB free for AM, SO and other processes)

That's not the only configuration you can use, there are others.

Conclussion, tunning spark is allways a hard task. You must know your cluster resources (memory, nodes, and cores).

Further information in oficial cloudera blog: https://blog.cloudera.com/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/